# Chown with dired over Tramp, from Windows machine

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, tramp

I launch dired over Tramp (from Win machine to Linux server):

```
C-x d /plink:user@server|su:root@server:/path-to-folder-controlled-by-root/
```

Then I type "O" to chown a folder, but I get `chown not supported on this system`.
Debugging, I can see the error stems from the definition of dired-of-chgrp, which makes the following verification :

```lisp
  (if (memq system-type '(ms-dos windows-nt))
      (error "chgrp not supported on this system"))
```

which obviously fails, because my machine is Windows — but I'm not chowning on Windows. Removing these two lines allows me to use the function normally.
I have the same issue with chgroup.

Does this mean my setup is incorrect, or is this a limitation?
What would be a clean way to correct this? Just removing these two lines seems like a dirty hack.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper fix would be

```
(if (and (memq system-type '(ms-dos windows-nt))
         (not (file-remote-p default-directory)))
    (error "chgrp not supported on this system"))
```

I've fixed this in the Emacs repository, will appear with Emacs 27.1.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I see that your code does not test if the distant system is Windows or not, is that because that type of verification is rare / difficult to make / useless ?

Comment: When you are on an MS Windows machine, Tramp does not give you access to another Windows machine.

Comment: I'm using `Emacs-25.3` and need to apply this fix. In which file, is it applied?

Comment: You can see the patch at <http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=d750b37cece666716d234c6e529a3f5d9bc56bd5>